# How to add Event Listener like "onclick method" to a button that will be rendered in an Email Template and Send to User Gmail using nodemail

Tags: node.js, mongodb, nodemailer

I have a custom Email Template for my project. I am sending this template using nodemailer to the user's Gmail account. What I want to do is to add an event listener to the buttons that I have added inside the template. I want to perform some database queries when the user clicks any of the buttons.

Answer (score 0):

1. emails do not support javascript, so an on-click event is impossible in an email
2. this does not mean that you cannot setup links and add `<a href="#" />` tags in your email template with prebuilt url's and setup a server to respond to the href

Comment: ook Thanks! the "a tag" works perfectly fine.